# Google App Scripts Function to Open URL

Tags: image, google-apps-script, hyperlink, google-sheets

I'm trying to add a link to an image in Google Sheets. I have tried the most commonly referenced function:

`=HYPERLINK( "http://www.google.com" ; IMAGE( "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" ) )`

However, I do not have access to a direct link to the image, as I cannot upload the image to a free image hosting site for security purposes, so I cannot use that function.

Now what I'm trying to do is link the image using Google App Scripts. I've noticed there is an option to "Assign Script" to an image after it has been added the the Google Sheet. However, I haven't been able to find script for a function to simply open a link when you click on the image and activate the function. Does anyone have a script I can use for this?

Comment: @JuanBravoRoig I've tried that script, when I copied and pasted it into my Google Apps Scripts document it did not function or allow me to attach it to the image.

Comment: Any error written anywhere? (browser's javascript console https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/ )

Comment: @nicolallias The error I am getting with the preexisting script is that it requires authorization, which will not go through.

Comment: @ClaraBertagnolli try running the script from script editor itself, does it run without errors?

Comment: If you still have a error ask a new question with error messages and [mcve]